# Return ID of authors who have at least one post

Tags: users, mysql, user-roles

I found a great piece of code [here](http://sltaylor.co.uk/blog/get-wordpress-users-by-role/) that returns the ID's of users by role. What I would like to do is modify it so it only returns the ID's of the users who have at least one post. I have tried to `INNER JOIN` the `$wpdb->posts` table and feel that I did that correctly but not sure. Here is what I have so far:

```
function getUsersByRole( $roles ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! is_array( $roles ) ) {
        $roles = explode( ",", $roles );
        array_walk( $roles, 'trim' );
    }
    $sql = '
        SELECT  ID, display_name
        FROM ' . $wpdb->users . ' INNER JOIN ' . $wpdb->usermeta . ' ON ' . $wpdb->users . '.ID=' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.user_id
        AND INNER JOIN '. $wpdb->posts .'  ON ' .$wpdb->users . '.ID=' . $wpdb->posts . '.post_author
        WHERE   ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.meta_key        =       \'' . $wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities\' 
        AND     (
    ';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ( $roles as $role ) {
        $sql .= ' ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.meta_value    LIKE    \'%"' . $role . '"%\' ';
        if ( $i < count( $roles ) ) $sql .= ' OR ';
        $i++;
    }
    $sql .= ' ) ';
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY display_name ';
    $userIDs = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );
    return $userIDs;
}
```

Which the SQL query outputs

> SELECT ID, display_name FROM wp_users INNER JOIN wp_usermeta ON
>   wp_users.ID=ba_usermeta.user_id AND
>   INNER JOIN wp_posts ON
>   wp_users.ID=ba_posts.post_author WHERE
>   wp_usermeta.meta_key =
>   'wp_capabilities' AND (
>   wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE
>   '%"author"%' OR wp_usermeta.meta_value
>   LIKE '%"editor"%' ) ORDER BY
>   display_name

I've never used `INNER JOIN` (or `JOIN`) so I could doing it wrong. I also think I need to do a count or something to make sure I get a result.

Any help would be awesome

**EDIT:** Here is the full working function as PHP for anyone who finds this later

```
    function getUsersByRole( $roles ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if ( ! is_array( $roles ) ) {
        $roles = explode( ",", $roles );
        array_walk( $roles, 'trim' );
    }
    $sql = 'SELECT ID, display_name
        FROM '. $wpdb->users .'
        JOIN '. $wpdb->usermeta.' ON ('.$wpdb->users.'.ID = '.$wpdb->usermeta.'.user_id AND '.$wpdb->usermeta.'.meta_key = \''.$wpdb->prefix.'capabilities\')
        WHERE ID IN (SELECT post_author FROM ' .$wpdb->posts.')
        AND(';
    $i = 1;
    foreach ( $roles as $role ) {
        $sql .= ' ' . $wpdb->usermeta . '.meta_value    LIKE    \'%"' . $role . '"%\' ';
        if ( $i < count( $roles ) ) $sql .= ' OR ';
        $i++;
    }
    $sql .= ' ) ';
    $sql .= ' ORDER BY display_name ';
    $userIDs = $wpdb->get_col( $sql );

    return $userIDs;
}
```

Comment: This seems OK, but it will return the same user multiple times because of the join. You now also restrict on editor or author: do you really need only the *current* authors or is it OK to return someone who used to be an author, wrote some posts back then, but currently has another role? Then you can leave out the join with `usermeta` and only join with the posts table.

Comment: I'm trying to create an author list page that shows all authors and editors that have at least one post. I just DON'T want to return Admin and Subscribers. Subscribers won't have post anyway and Admin shouldn't have post either.

Comment: Shoud I run another query to get all the post from the user then only ruturn ID if has post? (if so a little help with that :)

Comment: How many users and/or posts might you have for this site? The solutions on this page will all perform rather poorly once you start getting into 10,000 and especially 100,000+ records.

Comment: @mike right now I have like 4 users. I'm open to other solutions. Really the query is only being ran if the vist the `author` page which shouldn't have that much traffic. As I said other solutions are welcome :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of a `JOIN`, you can use a `IN` with a subquery, to prevent duplicate results because of the join:

```
SELECT ID, display_name
FROM wp_users
WHERE ID IN (SELECT post_author FROM wp_posts)
```

This will not look at capabilities. If you also want that you can add them like a join, but move the `meta_key` clause in the join, also to prevent duplicate results:

```
SELECT ID, display_name
FROM wp_users
    JOIN wp_usermeta ON (wp_users.ID = wp_usermeta.user_id AND wp_usermeta.meta_key = 'wp_capabilities')
WHERE ID IN (SELECT post_author FROM wp_posts)
    AND (wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%"author"%'
        OR wp_usermeta.meta_value LIKE '%"editor"%' )
```

Up to you to convert this back to PHP! Sidenote: Is the `wp_` in `wp_capabilities` dependent on the database prefix, or is it always `wp_`, even if your table names start with another prefix?

Comment: I don't use the `wp_` prefix and the meta key in the DB was set to my prefix. so the meta_key is `ba_capabilities` :) I think that's why if you look at the above code you'll see `$wpdb->prefix . 'capabilities\'`

Comment: @BandonRandon: Indeed, it was that line that made me think about it. Thanks for the confirmation!